# How to find absolute path of all symlinks in Unix system

Tags: unix, symlink, ls

I am currently using the following command to list all symlinks on the system.

```
ls -lR . | grep ^l > /usr/local/docato-composer/all-sym-links.txt
```

A line taken from the output

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          12 Jul 19  2010 sd3d -> dsk/c0t0d0s3
```

We are porting our application to a dedicated server so I need to get all the symlinks and then manually find the ones that are app specific to recreate them in the new server. How can I list all the symlinks on the system with absolute paths (/folder1/folder2/sd3d instead of sd3d)?

Comment: You're migrating a Docato instance to a new server? You are brave.  But Docato is [commercial software](https://www.flatironssolutions.com/news/flatirons-solutions-enters-into-exclusive-support-agreement-with-emc-for-docato-component-services-solution/). Support is available through commercial channels, is it not?  Have you considered instead of expending the time and effort to do this infrastructure migration, to instead migrate to a new (and better supported) CMS?  There are so many great ones to choose from in the open source world.

Answer (score 2):

I think `find . -type l -ls` is the command you are looking for.  (You might want to prune out the /proc filesystem etc.)

An extract of sample output (slightly edited to make it fit):

```
   678    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root      6 Oct 25  2014 /bin/open -> openvt
   141    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root      8 Feb 26  2015 /bin/ypdomainname -> hostname
   153    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root     20 Feb 26  2015 /bin/mt -> /etc/alternatives/mt
   155    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root      4 Feb 26  2015 /bin/sh.distrib -> dash
  5568    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root     14 Apr  6  2015 /bin/pidof -> /sbin/killall5
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like :

```
find . -type l -printf "\r\n%p -> %l"
```

Of course, you may use any separator you need instead of `->`.

Answer (score 0):

below shows you the symlinks in the current directory, recursively, but without following them, displayed with full paths and other information:

`find ./ -type l -print0 | xargs -0 ls -plah`

outputs looks about like this:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 apache develop 99 Dec  5 12:49 ./dir/dir2/symlink1 -> /dir3/symlinkTarget
lrwxrwxrwx 1 apache develop 81 Jan 10 14:02 ./dir1/dir2/dir4/symlink2 -> /dir5/whatever/symlink2Target
etc...`